# How can I hide Delete button from recyclerview, when the file is not exist?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, delete-file

Here is my recyclerView Adapter which shows a list from the database, View button is for downloading and the delete button deletes the file from device storage, it works perfectly. But how can I set Visibility of the delete button invisible/gone, if the file does not exist in the device storage.

```
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    ArrayList<DownModel> downModels;

    public MyAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<DownModel> downModels) {
        this.mainActivity =mainActivity;
        this.downModels = downModels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mainActivity.getBaseContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.elements, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {

        myViewHolder.mName.setText(downModels.get(i).getName());
        myViewHolder.mDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(myViewHolder.mDownload.getContext(), PdfView.class);
                intent.putExtra("pdf_url", downModels.get(i).getLink());
                intent.putExtra("pdf_name",downModels.get(i).getName());
                myViewHolder.mDownload.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        myViewHolder.mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = myViewHolder.itemView.getContext();
                String pdfName = downModels.get(i).getName()+".pdf";
                File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), pdfName);
                try {
                    if (file.exists())
                        file.delete();
                    Log.e("file","file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return downModels.size();
    }

}
```

RecyclerView

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FirebaseFirestore db;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
ArrayList<DownModel> downModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
MyAdapter myAdapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recycle);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    db=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    dataFromFirebase();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void dataFromFirebase() {
    if(downModelArrayList.size()>0)
        downModelArrayList.clear();

    db.collection("chapter1").orderBy("value")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {

                        DownModel downModel= new DownModel(documentSnapshot.getString("name"),
                                documentSnapshot.getString("link"));
                        downModelArrayList.add(downModel);

                    }

                    myAdapter= new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,downModelArrayList);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                }
            })

            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error ;-.-;", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
    ;


}
```

}
Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/down"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#A00303"
                android:elevation="7dp"
                android:text="View"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#A00303"
                android:elevation="7dp"
                android:text="Delete"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                tools:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check if file exists in `onBindViewHolder()`:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {

//check if file exists

Context context = myViewHolder.itemView.getContext();
String pdfName = downModels.get(i).getName()+".pdf";
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), pdfName);

if(file.exits()){

//file exists, show delete button
myViewHolder.mDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}else{
//file doesn't exist, hide delete button
myViewHolder.mDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

.........
.........
.........

}
```

**UPDATE:**

After the download is complete call this method on the adapter:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(myAdapter != null){
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: It's working only when I closed the app and reopen. When download completed it didn't show delete button, but if I closed the app and re-open it then it shows the button..I think view holder don't get updated..

Comment: How could I call this method? Since I did the download task in another activity.

Comment: If you do download in another activity, then in `onStart()` method of the activity that initialized the adapter call the method that I told you.

Comment: Getting this error after calling this methos on onStart()  
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.pdfapplication.MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference

Comment: In which activity do you create the adapter and set to recycler view?

Comment: I did it now on MainActivity,

Comment: Do you initialize the adapter in onCreate()?

Comment: Yes, I did in OnCreate. I initialize a method that fetches Data from firebase and set it to Adapter.

Comment: You need to notify the adapter in onStart() or onResume() so that it refreshes when you go back to MainActivity.

Comment: You have to override either onStart() or onResume() in your MainActivity. And notify adapter.

Comment: you can also check my update 2, but if it works then okay, GoodLuck,